# Need to know how IPv6 was disabled

Tags: networking, redhat, ipv6

I have a RHEL 6.3 server that has IPv6 disabled.  If I enter ifconfig I get the following:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:9F:0F:61  
          inet addr:10.3.72.76  Bcast:10.3.75.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1708252 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27566 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:409249072 (390.2 MiB)  TX bytes:4583283 (4.3 MiB)
```

My problem is that this lack of IPv6 caused our product to fail and I want to be able to reproduce this situation for a test case (so we don't fail this way in the future).  Unfortunately, I have no idea how IPv6 was disabled.

One way I know that disables IPv6 is to set NETWORKING_IPV6 and IPV6INIT to false in the /etc/sysconfig/network file.  This has not been done:

```
[root@foo bin]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=foo.ds.net
```

The other way I know is to disable the ipv6 module.  However, this also has not been done:

```
[root@foo bin]# lsmod | grep ipv6
ipv6                  322541  0
```

I would like to reproduce this situation as closely as possible but I have no idea what has been done to this server to disable IPv6.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to contact Red Hat Support, or looked in the knowledge base?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess would be some /etc/sysctl* settings, some script changing /proc/sys/net/ipv6/* or something like that in /etc/rc.local but it's hard to give an anwer as there are so many places where it could be done.

Comment: I mentioned the /etc/sysctl setting to the person that setup the server and that rang a bell.  They found a bunch of sysctl settings they had modified but had since forgotten about.

Comment: Some combination of `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1` presumably.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good answer, but I'll add my other scenario just in case: There is a bug in older versions of ifconfig which makes it stop showing ipv6 addresses when you have complex interface names. Use

```
ip -6 addr ls
```

to be sure of assigned IPv6 addresses.